# Backup Exec Remote Agent for IA64 architecture

Tags: backupexec, itanium

Does anyone know what is the best way to obtain a "Backup Exec Remote Agent" that works on the IA64 architecture?  I have the install CD for version 10d, but it appears to be incompatible.

I can't make any sense of Symantec's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having recently gone through figuring this out for ourselves, we've learned that 10d doesn't have any 64-bit support to mention. This may be wrong; as you say the Symantec website is pretty opaque. It also won't touch Server 2008 at all, even 32-bit versions. It is very old. And we're still using it.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh... memories of the heady Backup Exec 10 days! (I'd say that I remember them fondly, but I still have them going on at a few Customer sites. Heck, I've still got some Backup Exec 9.1 days going on... >smile<)

The ia64 agent is in the "RANT64" folder under your "Backup Exec" directory in your "Program Files" directory. The "RANT64EX" is the "extended" agent for x64 (aka x86-64, amd64).

Please accept my condolonces for having to deal with ia64 at all.

Comment: I've always thought that RANT64 was a highly appropriate name for it...

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your environment and for what version of BackupExec?  You could try just calling their tech support.